# Getting the same display for each contact

Tags: android, contacts

I am making a contacts manager using dummy data and I currently have a public field which contains an ArrayList of contact i.e. public static ArrayList contactList = new ArrayList();

Once I click on a particular contact (from the view contact screen), I am taken to the Edit Contact screen where it displays all the fields of that particular contact. i.e. name, mobile, address, email, etc. The first contact on the list has its details displayed correctly when clicked. However, when I go back to the view contact screen, it still displays the fields of the first contact.

In my MainActivity.java class:

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View clickedView, int clickedViewPosition, long id){
                TextView firstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstName);



                String fName = firstName.getText().toString();  


                Intent theIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), EditContact.class);
                theIntent.putExtra("firstName", fName);
                startActivity(theIntent);

            }

        });
```

I pass the firstName of the contact clicked into putExtra() and this takes me to the EditContact class where I run through the ArrayList and get the contact with the same firstName and then get all its fields (to store in the respective text boxes).

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Get saved data if there is any

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Designate that add_new_contact.xml is the interface used

    setContentView(R.layout.edit_contact);

    // Initialize the EditText objects

    firstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    lastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    dateOfBirth = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateOfBirth);
    mobileNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mobileNumber);
    homeNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.homeNumber);
    workNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.workNumber);
    homeEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddressHome);
    workEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddressWork);
    homeAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.homeAddress);
    workAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.workAddress);

    Intent theIntent = getIntent();

    String thefirstName = theIntent.getStringExtra("firstName");

    for (Contact con: MainActivity.contactList){

        if (con.getFirstName().equals(thefirstName)){
            firstName.setText(con.getFirstName());
            lastName.setText(con.getLastName());
            dateOfBirth.setText(con.getDateOfBirth());
            mobileNumber.setText(con.getMobileNumber());
            homeNumber.setText(con.getHomeNumber());
            workNumber.setText(con.getWorkNumber());
            homeEmail.setText(con.getHomeEmail());
            workEmail.setText(con.getWorkEmail());
            homeAddress.setText(con.getHomeAddress());
            workAddress.setText(con.getWorkAddress());

        }

    }


}
```

Does anyone know why the firstName that is passed in putExtra() does not change when I click on another contact?

Comment: please show the whole sourcecode of "onCreate" of the contact details activity

Comment: are you changing the string in the textview R.id.firstName

Comment: I thought that this would automatically change when you click on the contact. So if u click on the first one, it should get the firstname id for the first contact. Then when you click the second contact, it gets the id for the second contact. Is this correct?

Comment: I have shown the entire onCreate method now

Comment: But in your onItemClickListener you are not getting the string from the adapter or dataset according to the position where you are clicking.

Comment: Show the source code for MainActivity